# R - Find and Extract data from pipe delimited data

Tags: regex, r

I have the below data with pipe delimited.

```
ABC|12345|H|QWA|**X**|DFC-FED| MULTIPLE ENTRY

PQR|67890|D|WAS|||**Y**|OKA| UPDATE

XYZ|34567|V|**Z**|SDC| QUESTION

ASD|23412|G|QAS|||**Y**|BUT| DELETE

AFD|65432|H|**X**|AVB| QUESTION
```

I want to find and extract only X, Y, and Z which are present in Pipe delimited (For ex: |X|, |Y|, |Z|). The challenge here is they are not present in the same position for every record.

My output should be.

```
X
Y
Z
Y
X
```

Comment: Hi.  Have you had a go?  Its better if you post some code, you'll be more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sub,

```
sub(".*(^|\\|)([XYZ])(\\||$).*", "\\2", x)
```

or

If it should present inside  two pipes `|x|` then you may use the below regex.

```
sub(".*\\|([XYZ])\\|.*", "\\1", x)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tV1rL6/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot Avinash!! I am new to R string handling. If I dont have X or Y or Z in the data, I need to update it with NA. Can you please help me on this as well.

Comment: You have to add NA inside a string?

Comment: Yeah. Lets say my data is ABC|34567|V|SDC| QUESTION which does not contain |X| or |Y| or |Z|, I need to update the output as Not Applicable (NA).

Comment: after running the above command, you may easily find the rows which don't have X OR Y OR Z from that you may turn it to NA.

Comment: @ParthasarathyBalaraman you are looking for `grep` instead.